# Set maximum resolution for camera on Android

Tags: android, android-camera

Currently my application uses `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent to capture a video, but it seems I can't programatically set the maximum resolution (for example 720p).

Are there any methods/libraries to mimic this behavior, but at the same time with resolution control? Or should I create custom capture myself using `MediaRecorder`, `SurfaceView` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is wondering I've switched to https://github.com/JeroenMols/LandscapeVideoCamera/

This really allowed to change only a couple lines of code to work. The downsize is that it supports only landscape mode. But maybe this is a plus, since less people would record vertical videos.

Comment: Right, there is no way you can control resolution via Intent